# Insert data into versionInfo

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, fluent-migrator

i have added fluentmigration to execute migration with my sql script :

```
services.AddFluentMigratorCore()
                    .ConfigureRunner(
                        builder => builder
                               .AddSqlServer()
                               .WithGlobalConnectionString(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:StarNet"])
                               .ScanIn(typeof(AjouterColonneMFI_MNT).Assembly).For.Migrations().For.EmbeddedResources());
```

But when i have added a script that reference different database i have got an error :

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An error occured executing the following sql:
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[VersionInfo] ([Version], [AppliedOn], [Description]) VALUES (20200226120430, '2020- 
  02-27T13:27:34', N'TestDatabase')
   The error was object name 'dbo.VersionInfo' invalid.
```

here is my sql script that reference my first database'DEV_SHIVA', and another database 'DEV_OFFICE' :

```
USE [DEV_SHIVA]
GO

CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[SYN_OFFICE_DN_ACADOMIA_GetInterventionByIntervenantId] FOR [DEV_OFFICE].[dbo].[DN_ACADOMIA_GetInterventionByIntervenantId]
GO                                         

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DN_OFFICE_GetInterventionByIntervenantId]
       @INTERVENANT_BO_ID int
AS
BEGIN
SOME script

END
GO

USE [DEV_OFFICE]
GO



GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[DN_ACADOMIA_GetInterventionByIntervenantId] TO [DOMIAGROUP\StarNet]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[DN_ACADOMIA_GetInterventionByIntervenantId] TO [StarNet]
GO
```

Do you have any suggestion to how i can do migration when i have multiple database

Comment: the insert into [database].[dbo].[VersionInfo] is automatically done with fluentmigrator,  i didn't have to write that insert in my script

Comment: but you said that there is a script that reference different database. How `INSERT INTO [dbo].[VersionInfo]` will know what database need use?

Comment: because when i added fluentmigartor in my project i specified a connectionString .WithGlobalConnectionString(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:StarNet"]), and i am wondering how can i deal with the case when my script target multiple schema

Comment: stop, do you have multiple schemas or multiple database or both? because: "a script that reference different database" and "have multiple database schema"

Comment: it's multiple schema, i will post my sql script

Comment: https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator/issues/508

Comment: `USE [DEV_SHIVA]` and `USE [DEV_OFFICE]` doesn't change schema. It changes databases https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. Schema is `[dbo]`

Comment: so, again, do you have multiple schemas (dbo, ..) or multiple databases (DEV_SHIVA, DEV_OFFICE) or both?

Comment: I have write the wrong word, it's multiple database

Comment: How we can help you then if you don't know what  you're using? Where is `INSERT INTO [dbo].[VersionInfo]` in your script?

Comment: i write before that the line was generated and executed by fluentmigrator, and i was wondering if there is any way to handle aa scenario when you have multiple database

Comment: did you see the link to github above?

Comment: yes thanks i see it but not the same scenario

Comment: i found a solution is to add other fluentmigrator to my application with another connection string and use tags for each connection string